# keeping nav anchors on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am taking a intro to html and css class. Our instructor wanted us to create a basic bio site with five pages. He later asked us to add a blog page as well. When I added the sixth page button to the nav, it moved to under my fist button instead of to the right of the fifth button. I already acknowledge that is is probably a basic fix but I am only only a few months in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Here is my HTML code:

```css
    html { 
 background: rgb(167,207,223); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(167,207,223,1) 0%, rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(167,207,223,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(35,83,138,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(167,207,223,1) 0%,rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(167,207,223,1) 0%,rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(167,207,223,1) 0%,rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(167,207,223,1) 0%,rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient( startColorstr='#a7cfdf', endColorstr='#23538a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    body {
 background-color: #BDBDBD;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-right:25%;
 min-width: 600px;
 
    }


    header {
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%, rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%, rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(181,189,200,1)), color-stop(36%,rgba(130,140,149,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(40,52,59,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient( startColorstr='#b5bdc8', endColorstr='#28343b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }

    /*Navigation list styles */
    header nav {
    float: left;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    }

    header nav li {
   
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 80px;
    -moz-border-radius: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
    background: rgb(149,149,149); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(149,149,149,1) 0%, rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,  rgba(1,1,1,1) 50%, rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%, rgba(78,78,78,1) 76%, rgba(56,56,56,1) 87%,  rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(149,149,149,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(13,13,13,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(1,1,1,1)), color-stop(53%,rgba(10,10,10,1)), color-stop(76%,rgba(78,78,78,1)), color-stop(87%,rgba(56,56,56,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(27,27,27,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(149,149,149,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(78,78,78,1) 76%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(149,149,149,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(78,78,78,1) 76%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(149,149,149,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(78,78,78,1) 76%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(149,149,149,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(1,1,1,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(78,78,78,1) 76%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#959595', endColorstr='#1b1b1b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    
    }

    header nav li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
    }

    header article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    }
 
    section h1 {
   
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-family: nevis, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    }

    section {
    clear: left;
    width: auto;
    } 

    section h2 {
 padding-left: 20px;
    }

    section p {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-indent: 20px;
    }

    /* Footer Styles */

    footer {
    clear: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }

    footer address {
    background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%, rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%, rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(181,189,200,1)), color-stop(36%,rgba(130,140,149,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(40,52,59,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5bdc8', endColorstr='#28343b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 padding-top: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
  <li><a href="mbrooksbio.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="family.html">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a></li>
   </ul>
    </nav>
    
    
  
  
  </header>
     
  <section>
  <h1><br>THE MICHAEL BROOKS BIO PAGE</h1>
    <article>
   
   <h2><br><br>The Early Years</h2>
    <p class='home'> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
    </p>
   <h2><br>Fun in the Sun?</h2>
    <p class='home'>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor.  
    </p>
   
   <h2><br>Lemons to lemonade</h2>
    <p class='home'>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
    </p>
   <h2><br>A new direction</h2>
    <p class='home'>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. 
    </P>
   
    </article>
  </section>
  
  
  
  <footer>
   <address>13060 Cog Hill Way &bull;
      Orlando, FL 32828 &bull;
      (321)231-8966
   </address>
  </footer>
```

Comment: It's simply because the width of your nav elements is now wider than your nav container.  Make the nav li elements smaller, or increase the width of your nav element.  When you add 15% width (of the li) plus 5% margin (of the li), that's 20%.  20% x 6 = 120%, which is too wide for your nav element.  Needs to be <= 100%